# Android SQlite Trigger

Tags: android, triggers, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is a pretty specific question.  I've been trying to figure out exactly the steps needed, but I can't come up with anything that works.

I need a trigger that inserts new records into a table called Records, whenever a new task in the 'Task' table is inserted into the database.  I need to insert a record for each open item in the 'Items' table that matches the criteria in the task. My pseudo code/attempt at the statement follows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_item_records ON INSERT INTO tasks
BEGIN
   SELECT item in ITEMS WHERE item.type=new.type AND item.program=new.program
   ....now insert into records - this is where I'm confused
   INSERT  INTO records record.item = item.id, record.program = new.program, 
   record.task=new.id
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a `SELECT` statement inside a trigger is ignored.
However, the `INSERT` command [accepts a `SELECT` query as source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO records(item, program, task)
SELECT id, new.program, new.id
FROM items
WHERE type = new.type
  AND program = new.program;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great.  It's cool how you can mix the references to the new row with the column reference.  I had written code to do this without using sqlite, but this is approx. 50 lines shorter!

Answer (score 0):

> [CODE and CONCEPT HERE](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html)

Triggers are some `procedural code` executed when certain event occur in our `database`.

> Consider this simple demo for `trigger` which adds the field in canteen
>   and library automatically after insertion of new student in the
>   college.

```
CREATE TRIGGER if not exists add_student   
   AFTER INSERT  
 ON[student]  
   for each row  
     BEGIN  
        insert into library values (2 , new.sid );  
        insert into canteen values (3 , new.sid);  
     END;
```